# "Top of page" link

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, navigation

As long as I am always annoyed by links sending to the top of the current page on most web sites, SO is one that could really use one.

I mean, after reading all questions on e.g. "interesting" tab, to do anything useful you need to go to top menu, which means lots of scrolling. Such link could be viable on question pages after answers, but this would probably need more consideration. Hope I am not the only one who feels this way.

Please post your opinion on this subject.

Comment: I just hit **`Command + Up`**. I think this is the browser's responsibility, not the site's.

Comment: I think it's Control-Home to do that on Windowws, too.

Comment: @JeremyBanks - Isn't that `(Ctrl +) Home`?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - `Ctrl + PageUp/PageDown` cycles tabs in Chrome so that might be browser dependent.

Comment: @Scrooge I have neither a `Ctrl` nor `Home` key on my MacBook, and I just know what works for me. :P

Comment: ctrl+Home works in Windows, but my proposal stands

Comment: @JeremyBanks - I know, but I don't have a `Command` key on my Windows box ;)

Comment: @Scrooge Should be just the Home key.

Comment: @TimStone - Good point. Both work.

Comment: Home on Ubuntu with Firefox works for me as well, I use it regularly.  Just get into the habit :)

Comment: There are also browser add-ons that will give you a "scroll to top" button after having scrolled down a bit. It's not something the site needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to get to the top of any webpage by:

- **PC:** Pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> key.
- **Mac:** Holding down <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Up</kbd> key.
- **Mobile:** Tapping the status bar for most web browsers on the iPhone.

Comment: *Fn* +`Backspace` results in plain `Backspace` on my laptop (running Firefox 8 on Linux). Is this a Windows or Mac-only trick?

Comment: In Chrome on my Mac, it's Command-Up, like Jeremy commented.