# Keep voting buttons on screen through scroll in app

Tags: feature-request, voting, ios-app, scrolling

How cool would it be to keep the voting buttons and score affixed to the screen while you scroll through a long answer?

[image]

This is a fairly common mobile paradigm. Think of section headers when scrolling through a long list.

Note: there was a suggestion a couple years ago [regarding the desktop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124381/can-the-vote-buttons-have-a-fixed-position-when-a-user-scrolls-past-them), but I think it's even more important for mobile, since it's a lot easier to lose the buttons on a small screen.

Doing this with questions won't work because the gutter is only next to the title. For answers, the space is there, but unused.

Comment: Keeping a close eye on this discussion. We've considered adding a small header when scrolling on answers that says something like "Answer 1/4" and allows quick transitioning between them. We could also add votes there.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is going to be tricky to design, let alone code.

I really appreciate a large tap target on the screen when I want to vote, but when I'm reading a post that doesn't fit on the main screen, I don't want that tap target to take away from the main content.

As it's designed now for questions - the vote buttons take away from the width of the screen only for the title and not the body of the post. If you consider people that increase the font size (those that wear reading glasses normally) this change would really cut down on the content available.

I'd go the opposite and ask that the vote button not reduce the width of all answers and instead only cause the minimum portion of the answer to be indented to accommodate the voting controls. I'll probably mock up how I'd want the answers to show vote totals and voting controls and perhaps link here and ask for that request instead of this one.

I'm all for increasing voting and reducing friction, but unless this was accomplished without sacrificing screen real estate to render the main post and without making the overlay complicated or visually unappealing, I'd say leave the current design as is. Letting the vote buttons scroll off the top of the screen works well for my primary activity - consuming the content on a limited screen size iPhone/iPod.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was just looking at answers. Amending post to be exclusive to them

Comment: As for "going the opposite", do you have time to do a mock up? I can't picture a successful implementation of that