# Sticky votes needs CSS position sticky

Tags: feature-request, design

When scrolling, .vote.js-vote-sticky gets to be .is-stuck. But that's laggy because it's triggered by JS! :o

It should have [position: sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning). It's unacceptable to use a slower, inferior JS technique when there's a CSS alternative. Could the CSS equivalent be added, and optionally the JS used as a fallback for [crappy browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)?

… in addition to that, it seems like the JS solution is bugged when zoomed with "pinching" on Safari and flickers sometimes in other situations.

Comment: Wouldn't this just result in all the voting buttons piling up on top of each other?

Comment: @Shog No, they will stop being sticky after you scroll far enough that it'd be outside of the nearest ancestor without static position, if I understand it correctly. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/daker/ecpTw/light/).

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to [work in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646747/why-doesnt-position-sticky-work-in-chrome)?  Testing on Chrome 43.0.2357.81 in Windows 8.1.  It's very nice in Firefox, though.  Will look at the polyfill linked in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646747/why-doesnt-position-sticky-work-in-chrome/19266828#19266828) tomorrow.

Comment: I very infrequently recommend a polyfill, but in this case since sticky isn't in a standard, using it anyway could promote fragmentation and weakening of w3 standards. (also for Chrome support)

Answer (score 8):

It's literally five lines of css:

```
.votecell .vote {
    top: 0; 
    position: sticky; 
    position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

And it works perfectly! It's quick, doesn't extent past the comments, and is completely browser based.

([I came up with this feature request in 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124381/can-the-vote-buttons-have-a-fixed-position-when-a-user-scrolls-past-them), and it's great to see that it's being put into use.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want `resize` event listeners. So I use this userscript:

```js
// Hijack `$.fn.stick_in_parent`
Object.defineProperty($.fn, 'stick_in_parent', {
  set: function() { /* Ignore assignments */ },
  get: function() { return cssSticky;        }
});

// Use CSS instead of JS
function cssSticky(obj) {
  return this.css({
    position: 'sticky',
    top: obj.offset_top
  });
}
```