# Why not add a way to fully expand the question while writing an answer?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

While writing an answer, if you want to look at the original question, you need to drag down that bar. This is very awkward to do in mobile devices. For long questions, you often need to drag down, then scroll down, drag down, again scroll down...

Another problem, that happens in computers too, is that sometimes you will select some text in the question accidentally and drag down, making the `div` that contains the question scroll down. However, since the div does not have scroll bars, correcting that is not straightforward and looks really weird. This happened to me in a laptop with a touch pad, I apparently hit it while the mouse was over a partially visible question. This selected text in the question, and as I moved the mouse down, since touch pads have auto-drag-lock, the `div` scrolled down. It's hard to come out of the mess after that.

Why not add a button to expand the question all the way down?

Comment: To clarify, this is a problem in the mobile site?

Comment: The OP is speaking of mobile devices. If you are asking if what described is really a problem, I would say it is.

Comment: @kiamlaluno technically you can access the desktop version of the sites on mobile devices too, which leads to a different set of problems

Comment: I got it. I see I am assuming the OP is talking of the default theme visible in mobile devices, which is just an assumption.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. In mobiles, the problem is you have to scroll, drag, scroll, drag. A second problem happening in every device that doesn't have a mouse, but a touch pad or touch screen, is that text gets selected and the question's `div` scrolls down, so that now, instead of looking at the start of the question, you are looking at the end, which forces you to expand it all the way down to fix it.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. On my Android browser, even very long questions show without the need to expand anything. Can you post a screenshot of "that bar" that "you need to drag down"? Are you referring to a scrollbar? If so: is that a SE-specific scrollbar, or your browser's scrollbar? And is the 2nd problem (with the `div`) also solved when "expanding the question"? Oh, maybe you're referring to [some "top of page" link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118549/top-of-page-link)?